# Return a value from a multi value object in Javascript based on criteria

Tags: javascript, filter

Let's say I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  var obj1 = [{
          fullName ='Jon Doe',
          Name     ='Jon',
          age      ='17',
       },
       {
        fullName     ='Bob Smith',
        Name     ='Bob',
        age     ='34',
       }
   ]
```

If I have a `var CustomerName = 'Jon'`, how can I possibly retrieve the `age` for Jon

```
  var cName = obj1.filter(function(item)){
      return item['age'] //?? Where item['name'] == customerName
  }
```

I am a little lost, am i on the right path? THanks.

Comment: @pilchard - yes thank you. My google skills needs a little tuning

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
const filtered = (item) => {
  item.name === customerName
}

return obj1.filter(filtered).forEach((obj) => obj.age)
```

Comment: This is a clear [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/13762301) with more thorough explanation, flag instead.